# Unable to attach eventHandler in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been writing a javascript code that creates a button. But I'm unable to attach event handler to buttons. When I try to get child, it returns undefined. There are two functions, one creates button when window loads and other function tries to get the children.

```js
window.onload = function ()
        {
            f1();
            reader();
        }
       function f1()
       {
        var x = document.getElementById("buttons");
        for(var i=9;i>=0;i--)
        {
            
            var y = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            y.setAttribute("class","btn btn-primary btn-lg");
            y.setAttribute("id","mybtn");
            var z = document.createTextNode(i);
            
             y.appendChild(z);
            x.appendChild(y);
            
        }
       function reader()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("mybtn").firstChild;
            alert(x);
            
        }
```

```html
<div id="stage">
            <div id="screen">
                
                
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                
                
            </div>
            <div id="sb">
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's your code that tries to attach an event handler?  Your code does not show what the title asks.

Comment: Also, you cannot have multiple DOM objects with the same id value.  You are attempting to create 10 objects all with `id="mybtn"`.

Comment: i am trying to get all objects by child[0] but it returns undefined

Comment: Please show us the EXACT code that fails.  So far, you've shown a bunch of code and described a problem that is NOT illustrated by the code.  The fastest way to get help is to show the exact code you're using, describe what doesn't work, what you see in the debug console what you're trying to accomplish and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `}` end of `f1` function

```
 function f1()
 {
    var x = document.getElementById("buttons");
    for(var i=9;i>=0;i--)
    {

        var y = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        y.setAttribute("class","btn btn-primary btn-lg");
        y.setAttribute("id","mybtn");
        var z = document.createTextNode(i);

         y.appendChild(z);
        x.appendChild(y);

    }
 }
 function reader()
 {
        var x = document.getElementById("mybtn").firstChild;
        alert(x);

 }
```